# Retuse return statement or return by parameter reference

Tags: c++

What is the convention when it comes to returning values in functions?

Are both these excepted, or is one style prefered over the other?

```
MyObj
do_something(int n);

void
do_something(int n, MyObj& obj);
```

Thanks!

Edit: I'm sorry, I ment return by value in the first case.

Comment: There's no such convention, it depends on your concrete use cases.

Comment: `MyObj& do_something(int n);` is most likely going to return a dangling reference, this is not good.

Comment: Most likely you want to return by value.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `MyObj` by refference not because that is standard, but to avoid copying `MyObj` data which will ocurr if you will pass it by value. You can also pass it by pointer

```
void
do_something(int n, MyObj* obj);
```

and you will get similar behaviour: **you can modify object inside fuction and these modifications will be sustained as you leave function body**.

You can also pass numerous variables to your function that way and have them modyfied there without using `return` statement.

Having that in mind the better usage for `return` statement in your fuction is to track your fuction behaviour -  if your funtion fails in some point you can return appropriate error code:

```
bool do_something(int foo)
{
if(foo<0)
{
return false;// something went wrong - exit with error statement
}

// do something

return true; // everything is fine - exit with success statement
}
```

You can use `enum` strutures for better error management if you wish.

Getting modyfied data from a function by `return` is a good idea in cases where nothing can go wrong, like in some basic computations for example.

Answer (score 0):

As a very general rule, it's usually better to prefer a functional style
of programming, where each function returns a value, and modifies
neither global state nor other data, including anything indirectly
through pointer or reference parameters.  This is a very general rule,
however, and there are certainly exceptions.

The biggest argument in favor of the return value is that it means that
the client code doesn't have to define an instance before calling the
function.  If the type in question doesn't support default construction
(and a lot of user defined types won't), then you cannot use out
parameters.  And anything which might be used in an expression should be
returned by value as well, since you cannot use an out parameter in an
expression.  (Technically speaking, C++ doesn't support out parameters,
only in-out, since if you pass a reference or a pointer, it must refer
to or point to a valid object.  When we speak of out parameters in C++,
we generally mean only that the function ignores any previous value, not
that you can pass something without a previous value.  The exception is
the basic types, like `int`, which can exist in an uninitialized state.)

The most frequent case of using out parameters is for operations which
are likely to fail (for which failure is not an exceptional condition).
The classic example is reading a buffer, etc.; the `read` function will
return a status code indicating success or failure (sometimes in the
form of an integer specifying how many bytes were successfully read,
maybe with -1 as a sentinal value for true errors, as opposed to end of
file).  You could create a more or less complicated structure to return
all of the relevant information, but there's really no point in it,
since you have to handle it separately anyway.

Another frequent case where you have a (hidden) out parameter is in
non-const member functions.  In this case, the role of the function is
to modify the state of the object, so naturally, it treats the object as
an in-out parameter.